# Jest, test handler with middleware

Tags: aws-lambda, jestjs, handler

I have this handler using a middleware with [`Middy`](https://github.com/middyjs/middy).

```js
import middy from '@middy/core';
import httpErrorHandler from '@middy/http-error-handler';
import jsonBodyParser from '@middy/http-json-body-parser';
import asyncFunction from 'asyncFunction';

import { FeeLookupRequest } from '../types';

async function sampleFunction (
  event: { body: Partial<FeeLookupRequest> }
) {
  const body = event.body;
  try {
  const data = await asyncFunction(body);

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  };
  } catch (error) {
  return {
    statusCode: 400,
    body: JSON.stringify(error)
  };
  }
}

export const handler = middy(sampleFunction)
  .use(jsonBodyParser())
  .use(httpErrorHandler());
```

If this handler would be without the middleware (`export const handler = middy(sampleFunction).use etc`) I just simply do my test like this:

```js
import sampleFunction from 'itsRoute';

describe('description'. ()0> {
  it('without middleware', () => {
    const asyncFunction = jest.fn();
    // then a mock of the response and a mock of the input
    const response = sampleFunction(mockedInput)
    expect(response).toEqual(mockedResponse);
```

But here, by using `export const handler = middy(sampleFunction).use etc` I'm not sure how should I test, because I can't import directly the `sampleFunction` so how will I get the response of the handler?

Becase, I will import `handler` but it's the result of another function called `middy` that receives as parameter `sampleFunction`, so how should mock

Comment: Middy v1.x also uses `jest` for testing. I would take a look as some it the built in examples.